# ListPlot a list of Associations, with each pair in Association a different color

Tags: plotting, associations

As the title states, I'd like to `ListPlot` a list of `Association`s, with each pair in `Association` (i.e. a point in the plot) a different color.

Example set:

```
{<|9.59201 -> 1.77876, 7.90731 -> -0.196118, 10.1576 -> 0.914597, 
  8.35059 -> 1.54213, 8.61681 -> -0.32721, 8.61687 -> 0.841388, 
  8.71977 -> 0.775458, 8.04974 -> -0.05546|>, <|11.3369 -> 1.71693, 
  10.2098 -> 1.12961, 9.50776 -> 0.686906, 9.73273 -> 0.0918487, 
  8.63463 -> -0.551922, 9.69208 -> 0.0742091, 8.9928 -> 0.246726, 
  7.99068 -> 0.74243|>, <|30.1425 -> 7.22639, 27.3945 -> 2.77409, 
  33.4071 -> 13.1696, 29.2098 -> 2.26177, 27.0366 -> 1.54904, 
  29.9498 -> 0.379177, 25.5956 -> -0.373022, 
  29.3194 -> 4.75372|>, <|21.4029 -> 1.84701, 21.7417 -> -1.72672, 
  23.5003 -> -4.96554, 21.8775 -> -4.55523, 24.4923 -> -2.542, 
  22.1722 -> 3.32604, 26.3751 -> -0.232237, 
  22.2524 -> -1.3161|>, <|23.7269 -> 5.57226, 22.3803 -> 0.569165, 
  26.5645 -> 0.623679, 21.6979 -> -0.707441, 17.283 -> -2.45536, 
  20.3572 -> 1.23667, 20.9486 -> -2.83034, 
  21.0028 -> 1.51677|>, <|19.7322 -> -0.364163, 19.0351 -> -0.368039, 
  19.3306 -> -4.58427, 20.5308 -> -3.3369, 19.3743 -> 0.0137566, 
  25.7891 -> 13.2349, 18.5857 -> 1.42911, 
  19.0113 -> -0.679348|>, <|28.1422 -> 10.7682, 24.0284 -> 2.00734, 
  30.2609 -> 3.3972, 27.7815 -> 7.30809, 22.3967 -> 3.78583, 
  27.2537 -> -4.45777, 22.1055 -> -2.03305, 25.1709 -> 5.63689|>}
```

Comment: Each association has different color or each point? With 56 points there it will be hard to get distinguishable colors. p.s. have you tried anything?

Comment: That's my question too.  Can you explain in clearer terms how the colour of each point will be determined?

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, Indeed, 7 separate plots of 8 points. I tried Table[
 ListPlot[data[[r]],PlotStyle ->{#, PointSize[0.02]} & /@ (Hue[#, 0.5, 1] & /@ (Range[8]/8))] ,{r,7}] but I can't manage to get them colored separately

Comment: So in each of those 7 separate plots, each point has a different color?

Comment: Yup, each first key-value pair should have the same color across plots

Answer (score 2):

We have to convert associations, e.g: `<|1->2, 3->4|>` to something like `{ { {1,2} }, {{3,4}}}` so, not to the lists of pairs but lists of list with one element which is a pair. Then `ListPlot` will take those elements as separate plots.

```
ListPlot[
    #, BaseStyle -> AbsolutePointSize@15
] & /@ Apply[ List @* List, Normal[assoList], {-2}]
```

[image]

Comment: That's too bad, I had hoped to be able to take advantage of the Association structure. whatever works, works, though so thanks anyway. If you don't mind, I'll wait before accepting

Comment: @user18798 I don't know what do you mean ;) p.s. it's not safe to keep coordinates in `Association` take a look at `<|1->2, 2->5, 1->5|>`, it will merge duplicates which is not always something one would want.

Comment: True that. With e.g. labeling etc. I find it easier to just use Keys, and in my particular application, duplicate keys are non-existent :) but good to be informed about it in general

Comment: @user18798 You can use similar transformation inside `ListPlot`, mapping over list of associations so you can still refer to keys and values in `ListPlot`.

Comment: Why the List@*List btw? It somehow adds another depth level to the list

Comment: @user18798 yes, without one List we would have a list of pairs, and we want another list on each of them to make ListPlot thinking they are separate sets.